# add chartobject to excel via Python

Tags: python, excel

so I have been trying to add a chart object to an Excel file using IronPython and I keep getting an error whenever I call ws.ChartObjects. For some reason it tells me that its a DispCallable and that it has no Add property.

```
clr.AddReferenceByName('Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c')
from Microsoft.Office.Interop import Excel

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")
from System.Runtime.InteropServices import Marshal


def SetUp(xlApp):
    # supress updates and warning pop ups
    xlApp.Visible = False
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    return xlApp

def ExitExcel(filePath, xlApp, wb, ws):
    # clean up before exiting excel, if any COM object remains
    # unreleased then excel crashes on open following time
    def CleanUp(_list):
        if isinstance(_list, list):
            for i in _list:
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(i)
        else:
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_list)
        return None

    wb.SaveAs(str(filePath))
    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(False)
    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = True
    CleanUp([ws,wb,xlApp])
    return None

def GetWidthHeight(origin, extent, ws):
    left = ws.Cells(bb.xlRange(cellRange)[1], bb.xlRange(cellRange)[0]).Left
    top = ws.Cells(bb.xlRange(cellRange)[1], bb.xlRange(cellRange)[0]).Top
    width = ws.Range[origin, extent].Width
    height = ws.Range[origin, extent].Height
    return [left, top, width, height]

if runMe:
    message = None
    try:
        xlApp = SetUp(Excel.ApplicationClass())
        errorReport = None
        xlApp.Workbooks.open(str(filePath))
        wb = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook
        ws = xlApp.Sheets(sheetName)
        # i have no clue why ws.ChartObjects.Count throws an error all the time
        origin = ws.Cells(bb.xlRange(cellRange)[1], bb.xlRange(cellRange)[0])
        extent = ws.Cells(bb.xlRange(cellRange)[3], bb.xlRange(cellRange)[2])
        left = GetWidthHeight(origin, extent, ws)[0]
        top = GetWidthHeight(origin, extent, ws)[1]
        width = GetWidthHeight(origin, extent, ws)[2]
        height = GetWidthHeight(origin, extent, ws)[3]
        xlChartObject = ws.ChartObjects.Add(int(left), int(top), int(width), int(height))
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(extent)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(origin)
        ExitExcel(filePath, xlApp, wb, ws)
    except:
        # if error accurs anywhere in the process catch it
        import traceback
        errorReport = traceback.format_exc()
```

My problem is with calling ws.ChartObjects.Add() which throws an exception 'DispCallable' object has no attribute 'Add'. How do i go around this? What is wrong?

Comment: Is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621224/cant-get-excel-chartobjects-count.  Does it need to be `ChartObjects().Add()`?  If nothing else, it might resolve the issue mentioned in that comment. :)

Comment: @ByronWall this was it! Thanks! ChartObjects().Add() freaking differences between VBA and Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621224/cant-get-excel-chartobjects-count) indicating that `ChartObjects` is a function you should use

```
ChartObjects().Add(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.chartobjects.add.aspx), the arguments should be `double`. If this is not the issue, you can split

```
xlChartObject = ws.ChartObjects.Add(...
```

into

```
xlChartObjects = ws.ChartObjects
xlChartObject = xlChartObjects.Add(...
```

to start debugging. It is a good idea to:

1. Check available methods (for the class of `xlChartObjects`, e.g.) with [How do I get list of methods in a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911281/how-do-i-get-list-of-methods-in-a-python-class), or [Finding what methods an object has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439/finding-what-methods-an-object-has).
2. Check type with [What's the canonical way to check for type in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152580/whats-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-type-in-python).

You will likely learn how to fix these lines.

PS: In the code you posted `sheetName` and `bb` are not defined, although you probably define them earlier.

Comment: yes, sheet name is an input string so that's not an issue. bb is a name of a module that i defined and that was never a problem before. argument types should not be an issue either but i can cast them to test. Thanks for the tip.